# How to get value of key from properties file javaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have some javascripts in my html code,
I want to get the strings form my language.properties file;
Here is my language.properties file:

```
not_yet= you cant do this.
key=key
```

This is my javascript code:

```
var not= you cant do this.
```

How can I do it?

For example in my html I did somthing like this:

```
<fmt:setBundle basename="language"  />
    <th><label style="float:right;"><fmt:message key="key" /></label></th>
```

I saw some sulotion to do that in javaScript code but it's not working for me:

```
var someJSValue = '${language.key}';
```

Thank you!

Comment: Think about where things are and where they're running. Your JSP code which has access to your properties file is on the **server** and runs when the server is fulfilling a page request; your JavaScript code in your HTML runs **later**, on the **client** -- an entirely separate machine (usually).

Comment: So what? can't I get some value from this file by javascript? In the html code I did it, and its working well..

Comment: *"In the html code I did it"* No, you didn't. You probably used a scriptlet -- JSP code embedded in your HTML. You can do the same thing in your JavaScript code if it's in an HTML file (or if you set up a JSP to run and return JavaScript), but that's **not** JavaScript accessing your properties file, no more than what you've done is HTML accessing your properties file.

Comment: @ T.J. Crowder Do you have idea for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to put the value of `<fmt:message key="key" />` in a js var you can write code like this:

```
var someJSValue = '<fmt:message key="key" />';
```